# Wordpress multilingual urls

Tags: wordpress, url, plugins, translate, multilingual

I am trying to create a multilingual website with worpdress. So far I have created a website that has different content depending on the language in the url.
But I am also trying to have the urls translated in the selected language.

So for example if I make a page in wordpress, and translate it into 3 different languages it should generate 3 different page names for that single page.

For example the page is called hello world and the language is english the urls should like this:

```
en.foo.com/hello-world/
```

But if the language is netherlands the url should like this:

```
nl.foo.com/hallo-wereld/
```

And both urls are the same page in wordpress, only the url should be translated.

Currently I am using qTranslate-X for the translate of the website.

How can I can do this?

Comment: There is an option for this in the qTranslate-X settings...

Comment: @Rich I heard that before, but I can't seem to find that anywhere. Do you know what the option is called like ? The first part I already have so that the nl. stand infront of the url

Comment: In the Advanced Settings you can determine how urls are rewritten for the different languages. Options are:

Via query mode (http://yoursite.com/?lang=en)
Pre-path mode (http://yoursite.com/en/)
Or pre-domain mode (http://en.yoursite.com/)

Comment: @Rich Yes i know that, i already said that i have accomplished that. But i meant the name of the post in this case: hello-world. That has to be translated to different languages. Do you know anything for that ?

Comment: Aha, sorry @persa you need this plugin for that [https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/qtranslate-slug](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/qtranslate-slug)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to translate my website with several free plugin, but personally [WPML](https://wpml.org/)  is the best option although it is not free, this plugin offers you the possibility to do string translation, language switcher, page duplication, permalinks etc.